# InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 199 on production, Laravel 5.2.39

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I use Socialite 2.0 and Laravel 5.2.39. The social login on localhost:8000 is working properly but It doesn't work on the production site (example.com).

`public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    ....
}`

The exception error when call `Socialite::driver($provider)->user()` function is:

> InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 199

I tried all solutions people suggested but no luck.
Here is some configuration

`SESSION_DRIVER=file
DOMAIN=example.com
URL=http://example.com (used in config/app.php)
DOMAIN=mysite.com (used in config/session.php)`

Here are the routes:

`Route::get('redirect/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
 Route::get('callback/{provider}', Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');`

Thanks for helping!

Comment: If I use Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user(), an other error occurs:

``ClientException in RequestException.php line 107:
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"Missing authorization code","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"EamBm42\/suf"}}``

Comment: Finally I found the solution. It's related to Nginx configuration.
Use `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`
instead of `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;` on file /etc/nginx/sites-available/<example.com>.

Comment: Man, you juste saved my life ! Put it as an answer, this problem touch a lot of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. It's related to Nginx configuration. Use try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args; instead of try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string; on file /etc/nginx/sites-available/.

Comment: Hey, still I am not getting this. Please explain more.